# System::Object to int or double in C++/CLI

Tags: sql, c++-cli, ole

I'm taking some information from data base and i want to use it in calculations. But due to what i'written, i'm not able to convert it to number. I recieve `System::Object^`. here is the part of code:

```
OleDbConnection ^ cnNwind = gcnew OleDbConnection();

cnNwind-> ConnectionString = 
L"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" 
L"Data Source = C:\\temp\\A.mdb";

try
{
    // Open the database
    cnNwind->Open();
    Console::WriteLine(L"Connected to database successfully!");

    // Count the customers
    OleDbCommand ^ cmProducts = gcnew OleDbCommand();
    cmProducts->CommandText = L"SELECT ID FROM Table1";
    cmProducts->CommandType = CommandType::Text;
    cmProducts->Connection = cnNwind;

    // Print the result
    Object ^ numberOfProducts = cmProducts->ExecuteScalar();
    Console::Write(L"Number of products: ");
    Console::WriteLine(numberOfProducts);
}
catch (OleDbException ^ pe)
{
    Console::Write(L"Error occurred: ");
    Console::WriteLine(pe->Message);
}
// Close the connection
if (cnNwind->State != ConnectionState::Closed)
{
    cnNwind->Close();
}

Console::WriteLine(L"The database connection is closed...");
```

I want to use `numberOfProducts` as a digit. I mean type `double` or `integer`. How can i transform it?

Comment: Looks like c# to me (rather than c++) You will get better answers if you modify the tags and format your code samples properly (use the {} symbol above where you enter the question)

Comment: @Tom, it's C++/CLI.  You're right that it's a very different language from C++.

Comment: Guys, i'm not really sure what i am doing, cause it just was the only working variant of database connection. I wasn't able to do it with simple c++. Can you tell me how cat it be done? And anyway, how can i use this numberOfProducts further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`safe_cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23b7yy6w.aspx) to cast the `Object^` to the appropriate type. This is covered in detail on this page: [How to: Use safe_cast in C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bh3t52k.aspx)

```
Object^ numberOfProductsObj = cmProducts->ExecuteScalar();
// IIF the underlying type is System::Int32
int numberOfProducts = safe_cast<int>(numberOfProductsObj);
// or, IIF the underlying type is System::Double
double numberOfProducts = safe_cast<double>(numberOfProductsObj);
```

Since there can only be one underlying type (and I don't know what it is in your case), only one of these will work -- the other will throw an exception. Point being, your first step is to determine the actual underlying type (presumably `double`, `float`, or `int`).

Comment: By the way, if i want to take out a char[20] from a database can i use the same method or i should do some changes?

Comment: @KAGDGAP : `char[20]` would be marshaled as `System::String^`, so the easiest thing to do would be to use `System::Object::ToString()`: `Object^ someStringObj = /*...*/; String^ someString = someStringObj->ToString();`

Comment: Look here, i've got one mroe problem. My query can return some kind of a table, that can have more than one row, and i need to take each cell in a different variable (may be in list or array). Can you help me to write it? or describe steps?

Comment: @KAGDGAP : That sounds like it needs sufficient explanation/code demonstration as to warrant a new question. I recommend you do that, and I'll try to help there.